# Find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/{ (4-{1\over{n}})^n}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of  the following power series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^n\over(4-{1\over{n}})^n}$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: the ratio test but i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: @jake: what was the limit of the ratios?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The [Cauchy-Hadamard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) test is probably better.

$$\frac 1R = \limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}$$

The solution should be

> $R = 4$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The ratio of terms $n$ and $n+1$ is
$$
\frac x4\frac{4(4-\frac1n)^n}{(4-\frac1{n+1})^{n+1}}
$$
Consider the limit as $n\to\infty$.